# Increasing the memory of a single node in GCP Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I have a GCP Composer instance running with 3 nodes (which is the minimum possible). The nodes of this instance have 4GB of memory. However, I have a job that requires 8GB of memory. Is it possible to adjust  the memory of just a single node? I don't want to upgrade my whole Composer instance to 8GB, because that would dramatically increase the cost.

Comment: Have you explored running your job on a Kubernetes cluster? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html

Answer (score 1):

Thought it is not recommanded, you can upgrade the machine type used by your Cloud Composer cluster by removing and create again de `default-pool`.

There's an [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/updating#upgrading_the_machine_type_for_gke_nodes) on how to to this.

It might not show in the Composer UI or in the Composer settings returned by CLI.

Also, you can as suggested in [parakeet's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65886555/increasing-the-memory-of-a-single-node-in-gcp-composer/65905447#comment116492214_65886555) use a `KubernetesPodOperator` or `GKEPodOperator` in order to properly dimension the node pool used to instanciate the pod.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud composer runs on [several components](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/architecture). the workers are typically nodes in a Kubernetes cluster. AFAIK, you can set up CLoud Composer with only 1 node pool and so, all the workers have the same configuration.

In a perfect world, you could have the capacity to define different worker node pool with different type of VM, including preemptible VMs. It's not yet the case.

Comment: you can update the default node pool : https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/updating#upgrading_the_machine_type_for_gke_nodes

Comment: Yes, but you can't have 2 node pools, 1 with 4Gb of memory and the 2nd one with 8Gb of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is [no way](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools#:%7E:text=A%20node%20pool%20is%20a,contain%20one%20or%20multiple%20nodes.) to change just one node in a node pool. I also didn't want to update the default node pool because then I'd by switching from three 4GB machines to three 8GB machines, [doubling the costs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing). Besides that, the minimum number of nodes for the default-pool created by GCP Composer is 3, thus, there is also no way to reduce the costs by reducing the number of nodes.

I ended up creating a new node pool having a single machine with 8GB, 0 nodes, and enabling autoscaling (with minimum nodes: 0, maximum nodes: 1). Now, if I have a job that requires more than 4GB of memory, I can simply run it and GCP automatically allocates the 8GB machine and automatically deletes it afterwards.

I think this is the best solution because the new machine is not always in use, and it's just a single machine.